# paypal android sdk 2.0.2

Tags: android, eclipse, paypal, sdk

I have trouble to use Environment_Sandbox Authentication with the current sdk sample (sdk 2.0.2) on github.

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "APP-8...T"; //My Applications Sandbox ID
```

When I start the Sample App, I get an Internal Server Error 500

> 03-25 12:01:07.638: W/E(5450): N SN:9 PayPal-Debug-Id header: 9a47bfc322244
>   03-25 12:01:08.549: W/E(5450): Z SN:10 PayPal-Debug-Id header: 6bbb589472f2c
>   03-25 12:01:08.559: E/paypal.sdk(5450): request failure with http statusCode:500,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
>   03-25 12:01:08.559: E/paypal.sdk(5450): request failed with server response:
>   03-25 12:01:08.589: E/PayPalService(5450): INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

And no, I have not an ampersand in my password (I'm not even to enter it).

Is there an error in the sdk or what is the problem?

tia, Stefan

edit: the Sandbox ID is for all apps and all users the same. How is a single app identified? In older versions of the sdk there was properties like receiver_email, api username or signatur. In the current version there is only the clientId. I'm confused about that ...

solved: my mistake was that I create a "classic API app" but I need a "REST API app". With the credentials of the REST-API-App it works now. I don't delete this topic - perhaps it will help someone ...

Comment: Did you get to know that where we can specify receiver_email in Paypal SDK 2.0.?